# Issue with Redis managing Laravel Queues

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I am using Laravel forge with Redis as the queue driver.

I have updated the code for my application to send push notifications a few times over, but the notifications sent are as in the old code.

Changing the queue driver to database, sends the notifications as per the latest updates. However when I switched it back to Redis, it still shows old version of the notification.

I have done "FLUSHALL" via redis-cli, but it didn't fix it.

Also I use Laravel Horizon to manage queues.

How I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Other thing I noticed was all code driven dispatches were queued on Redis. I have listed the solution in the answer in the hopes it would help someone else.

Comment: sure you did check the .env file and not your config file?

Comment: Yes. I've check on .env.

Comment: Did you flush the right db in redis?

Comment: Doesn't flushall flush all db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I received from Forge support:

> Hello,
>
> There might be a worker that's stuck you can try and run `php artisan
>   horizon:purge` which should kill all rogue worker processes, and then
>   restart the daemon. It's advised to run the purge command in your
>   deployment script to make sure all stale processes are killed.
>
> -- Mohamed Said forge@laravel.com

However this how I got it sorted:

`php artisan horizon:terminate`

`php artisan queue:restart`

And then the code was working properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51570378/470749 similarly said `php artisan queue:restart` which is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Stop redis, Stop Horizon workers. Start redis and then start horizon workers.
But before these all clear cache.

I had similar problem and in my case it was just the matter of restart all the services.